# Computer doesn't accept SSL/TLS connections

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ssl

So my new Dell 7490(running Win 10, 64 bit) refuses all connections involving SSL/TLS, but allows http.

The browser is useless and most programs are broken. I've tried switching out the OS for Ubuntu, reinstalling the wireless drivers, resetting the network settings, and using an external wireless adapter instead of the network card inside the computer. None of this worked. As far as my limited knowledge goes, I've tested the OS, hardware, and driver...so I'm completely stumped at this point.

Connecting to 192.168.1.1, 127.0.0.1 and most http sites work.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: The errors I get in browser are:
Chrome-
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
Firefox-
SSL_ERROR_BAC_MAC_ALERT
SSL_ERROR_BAC_MAC_READ

I think these last two are especially valuable. baidu.com and sohu.com regularly load, both of which using http. I've made a video for greater detail:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M-fHvNrFh94

Comment: Are other devices on the same network able to make TLS connections? What behavior or error messages fo you get when attempting TLS connections?

Comment: Given that this is independent of the OS it sounds more like a network issue, i.e. some firewall or similar (like a router with builtin firewall) is restricting the traffic.

Comment: Yes, other devices on the network can make TLS connections.

Comment: I tried disabling Windows Firewall, and I don't think the router is the thing affecting it(I've tried connecting to a hotspot on my phone as well, and same issue).

Comment: Try installing a packet capture tool, such as Wireshark. It might not show anything, but it might show that the router is sending a plaintext error message...

Comment: Is this machine on a personal or company network?

Comment: The machine is on a personal network. How should I send the wireshark data?